# convert to proper case using dax

Tags: dax

I have a text column and would like to convert it to Proper. Is there a way to do it using DAX only? I dont want to use inbuilt powerbi functions

Proper case is any text that is written with each of the first letters of every word being capitalized. For example, "This Is An Example Of Proper Case." is an example of sentence in proper case. Tip. Proper case should not be confused with Title case, which is most of the words being capitalized.

for example

```
text_column
apple bat
cab
```

should change to

```
Text_column
Apple Bat
Cab
```

Comment: I made an edit of my answer which may interest you.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to convert text string to proper case with DAX. Start with a sample table:

```
Table = 
    DATATABLE(
        "ID" , INTEGER ,
        "Text" , STRING ,
        {   
            { 1 , "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" } ,
            { 2 , "Happy Birthday" }
        }
    )
```

Then add this DAX code as a calculated column:

```
Text Proper = 
VAR SplitByCharacter = " "
var var_text = 'Table'[Text] 
VAR Table0 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATE (         
            CALCULATETABLE( 'Table', 'Table'[Text] = var_text ), // we shrink table to current row only
            VAR TokenCount =
                PATHLENGTH ( SUBSTITUTE ( 'Table'[Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ) )
            RETURN
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, TokenCount )
        ),
        //"Word", PATHITEM ( SUBSTITUTE ( 'Table'[Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ), [Value] ),
        //"cnt", PATHLENGTH ( SUBSTITUTE ( 'Table'[Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ) ),
        "Proper", 
            var word = PATHITEM ( SUBSTITUTE ( 'Table'[Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ), [Value] )
            var word_Propper = UPPER( LEFT( word, 1 ) ) & LOWER( RIGHT( word, LEN( word) - 1 ) )
            return
                word_Propper
    )
RETURN 
    CONCATENATEX( Table0, [Proper], " " )
```

I cooked this code with inspiration of the article by Phil Seamark:

https://dax.tips/2019/07/05/dax-pivot-text-into-a-list-of-words/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in Power Query Editor as shown below-

[image]

The output will be as below-

[image]

Comment: i need to do it using dax code only...could you share the code?

Comment: i tried to use `text.proper` but that doesn't work :(

Comment: No dax code used here. Its a direct transformation of data in power query. Just select the column you wants to transform and do what is shown in the image.

Comment: i need a dax code based solution...wont be able to use this one

Comment: Text.Proper is not a DAX as well. You can use that in Power Query and Text.Proper also giving me the same output you wants. Please let me know what issue you are facing and also provide the fill code for Text.Proper you are using.

Comment: No such option yet available in DAX. You have to perform that transformation in M Query (Power Query Editor) using option I have shown in the answer or using Text.Proper with a custom column.

Comment: @mkRabbani Just spark your curiosity - I made it in DAX :-) See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Nome Mes Abrev = 
 UPPER(LEFT((FORMAT(dCalendario[Date],"MMM")),1)) &
 LOWER( RIGHT(FORMAT(dCalendario[Date],"MMM"),LEN(FORMAT(dCalendario[Date],"MMM")) - 1 ) )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you're just doing one word, here's a solution. I used it for a greeting to extract the person's first name from USERPRINCIPALNAME().

```
User Greeting = 
var usersNameLength = SEARCH(".",USERPRINCIPALNAME())
var firstName = LEFT(USERPRINCIPALNAME(),usersNameLength-1)
var formattedFirstName = UPPER(LEFT(firstName,1)) & Mid(firstName,2,usersNameLength-1)

return
"Welcome to Reporting Links "  & formattedFirstName
```